# Use Variational Inference to find an approximate of distribution

Tags: optimization, random-variables, statistical-inference

I have learnt about Variational Inference at this [website](https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/inference/variational/).

In my understanding, it is a method that sampling random variables from an easy distribution $q$ which is most similar to an intractable distribution $p$.
In order to do that, i must firstly find the easy distribution $q$. To find $q$, my objective is optimize this:
$$\min \limits_q J(q) = \min \limits_q \sum\limits_x q(x)\log\dfrac{q(x)}{p(x)}   \text{ with } q(x) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^nq_i(x_i)$$
But I don't know what exactly to do because the $p$ is unknown. Can I give some assumption about $p$ ?

For example, give a dataset of data points coming from an unknown distribution $p$:
$$\mathcal{D} = \{1, 2, 4\}$$
Can I assump that $p$ is Uniform Distribution with $p(1) = \dfrac{1}{3}$, $p(2) = \dfrac{1}{3}$, $p(4) = \dfrac{1}{3}$ ? Then if I assump that $q \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ so my objective is just find $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to minimize $J(q)$, like this:
$$\mu^*, \sigma^* = \arg \min \limits_{\mu, \sigma} \sum \limits_{x \in \mathcal{D}} \mathcal{N}(x;\mu, \sigma)\log\mathcal{N}(x;\mu, \sigma)$$

Can anyone tell me that if i'm correct or not ?

Comment: The website you linked looks like a nice resource... But I would suggest that you also have a look at Murphy's book on the topic. Reading through Murphy carefully should clarify things

Comment: @Oxonon Can you give me a confirmation that i'm wrong or not ?

Comment: What you've written above is quite muddled. Wrong, in short. And Murphy's 'machine learning: a probabilistic perspective' book does a much better job of presenting the right way of looking at it (with examples, plots etc), than I ever could. Hence my recommendation.

Comment: @Oxonon Thank you for your help ^^